# Instructions for lego bag with 135149 (yellow and red bricks)

Tags: set-identification

Please let me know if you know what set this goes with.  This is everything I have. [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These bags are from [31112 Wild Lion](https://rebrickable.com/sets/31112-1/wild-lion/):

[image: Set Box]

This set includes 4 bags, so you appear to have everything. The [instructions](https://rebrickable.com/instructions/31112-1/) are available on Rebrickable.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!!

Comment: @emith Make sure you click to accept the answer (which beat me by a minute!) <https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers>